# How do we know that we can interpret the torah non-literally beyond what is found in the talmud?

Tags: tanach, drush, literalism

I have often heard "drashot" or homiletic interpretations of many verses in the torah. How do we know that the torah can be explained in a non-literal way beyond the non-literal explanations found in the talmud and its contemporary literature such as midrash. Meaning, if a certain drasha of a pasuk is not found in the gemarah or midrash can a person simply make it up on his own? If not what are the parameters for creating a non-literal interpretation?

Comment: Related/answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10868/the-midos-by-which-the-torah-is-expounded-rabbi-eliezer-the-son-of-rabbi-yosi-h

Comment: @Yishai I believe those are ways to expound the torah logically/halachically, not morally/homiletically

Comment: See point (c) in Alex's answer there, quoted from a Ba'al Tosefos.

Comment: Why would we need to be allowed to do so?

Comment: I am not aware of any rabbinic figure who has expressed a view that the biblical text only carries one level of meaning. It seems to have been the universal concencus that text carries multiple levels of meanings, thus justifying further post-talmudic exegesis. Furthermore, the raelm of drash can be used as a mere medium to convey information, even if one does not believe that it is the intent of the verse at all.